# Not able to upload app to test flight from XCode 13 (App Store Connect Operation Error)

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, applet, app-store-connect

recently I am facing problem uploading my archive to test flight/ app store using XCode 13.2. Now I am using the latest version but for 13.1 version also I faced the same issue (App Store Connect Operation Error at last stage).

Firstly I thought this could be my internet, but even after changing WiFi I am not able to upload it.

Other solution is to use the Transporter app. There also it's same. But there it does not throw any error, rather it will be stuck in the "delivering app to the app store" stage for ever. Even after 2 hours it's not able to upload the app, needless to say that I am using 150mbps connection.

What can be the possible reason for this? And how can I solve this?
This is happening 10/10 times, it's not random error anymore.

Comment: Could you please add the entire error message, so its easier to understand your problem